# dplyr mutate: solve unique names error

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 10 columns. For the example this is the dummy version:

```
df = tbl_df(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

I want to do this in dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V6), V2, paste(V2,V3,sep=" ")))
```

I obtain:

```
Error: Each variable must have a unique name.
```

But if I do:

```
df$V2 = ifelse(is.na(df$V6), df$V2, paste(df$V2,df$V3,sep=" "))
```

it works.

How can I do the last step with `dplyr` statements?

Comment: Why don't you do `df %>% mutate(V2=ifelse(is.na(V6), V2, paste(V2,V3,sep=" ")))`?

Comment: Yes, I did that !! it says `Error: Each variable must have a unique name.`

Comment: When I do this with your dummy df, it works. Check the column names of your real df.

Comment: haha, thanks
I did look in case and in my file the names are V1,V2,V3...

Comment: Example works for me too. What version of `dplyr` do you use?

Comment: Right now, I can't reproduce your problem, try to include a `dput()` of your dataframe or if it's too big, a part of it.

Comment: As @Lamia said, the problem most likely lies with columns names. Try: `df %>% 
  setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V6), V2, paste(V2, V3, sep = " ")))`

Comment: `df` and `p9` are mixed in the last line of code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Lamia said, the problem most likely lies with duplicate columns names.

Create sample dataframe with duplicate column names. You should *never* do that:

```
wrong_df <- data.frame(
  V1 = 1:3,
  V2 = 1:3,
  V3 = 1:3,
  V6 = c(4, NA, 6),
  V1 = 7:9,
  check.names = FALSE
)
wrong_df
#   V1 V2 V3 V6 V1
# 1  1  1  1  4  7
# 2  2  2  2 NA  8
# 3  3  3  3  6  9
```

Reproduce the issue:

```
library(dplyr)
wrong_df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V6), V2, paste(V2, V3, sep = " ")))
# Error: Each variable must have a unique name.
# Problem variables: 'V1'
```

Solve it by deduplicating column names with `make.names()`. Note that the second `V1` column has been renamed `V1.1` (see `help("make.names")`):

```
wrong_df %>% 
  setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(is.na(V6), V2, paste(V2, V3, sep = " ")))
#   V1  V2 V3 V6 V1.1
# 1  1 1 1  1  4    7
# 2  2   2  2 NA    8
# 3  3 3 3  3  6    9
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!!
what I did was to put "weird" names like "age", "city", etc and it worked
sure there was a duplicate :)